# Every club of $\kappa$ in $M[G]$ contains a club in $M$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

I'm trying to solve exercise (H1) of chapter VII on Kunen's Introduction to Independence Proofs and I would like some hint. I would prefer a hint instead of the full solution :)

Assume in M that $\kappa>\omega$, $\kappa$ is regular and $\mathbb P$ has the $\kappa$-c.c. In $M[G]$, let $C \subset \kappa$ and $C$ c.u.b. Show that there is a $C' \in M$ subse of $C$ c.u.b. in $\kappa$. Hint: in $M[G]$, let $f: \kappa \rightarrow \kappa$ be such that $\forall \alpha < \kappa(\alpha < f(\alpha) \in C)$ and apply lemma 6.8

Lemma 6.8 states that assuming that $\mathbb P \in M$, $A, B \in M$ and in $M$, $\theta$ is a cardinal, $\mathbb P$ has the $\theta$-c.c. and $f \in M[G]$ with $f:A\rightarrow B$, then there is a map $f:A\rightarrow \mathscr P(B)$ with $F \in M$, $\forall a \in A(f(a)\in F(a))$ and $\forall a \in A(|F(a)|<\theta)^M$.

I have noticed that there is already a question like this one, right here [If P is k-c.c. and C is club in k in M[G] then C contains a club in M](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25264/if-p-is-k-c-c-and-c-is-club-in-k-in-mg-then-c-contains-a-club-in-m?rq=1), but in this question, the Kunen's hint was not used. **I would like to use it.**
Any hints?

Comment: You use $f$ twice in the lemma.

Comment: I'm thinking about defining $C'$ as JDH did here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25264/if-p-is-k-c-c-and-c-is-club-in-k-in-mg-then-c-contains-a-club-in-m?rq=1 and use lemma 6.8 to show $C'$ is closed. Is it possible?

Comment: I wonder whether Kunen is suggesting that the exercise is solvable without any forcing machinery. Is it true in general that, given a pair of models $W\subseteq V$ where every $x\in V$ which is a subset of $W$ can be covered by a $y\in W$ of size at most $\kappa+|x|^V$ (i.e. satisfying Hamkins' $\kappa$-covering property), every club on $\kappa$ in $V$ extends a club in $W$?

Comment: The answer to my question is negative. We can get a counterexample by forcing over $L$ to shoot a club through a stationary costationary subset of $\omega_1$. Since $0^\sharp$ is not added, $\omega_1$-covering holds by Jensen's covering lemma, but the new club doesn't contain an old club by costationarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially the same idea from Joel's proof: Let $f$ and $F$ be as above. For every $\alpha<\kappa$ define $G(\alpha)=\sup F(\alpha)$. It's easy to see that for every $\alpha$, $\alpha<G(\alpha)$. Now let $G^{\omega}(\alpha)=\lim_{n<\omega}G^{(n)}(\alpha)$. Let $D=Range(G^{\omega})$. $D$ is clearly unbounded, so it's enough to show that $D\subseteq C$. In order to see that, note that for every $\alpha$ and every $n$, $G^n(\alpha)<f(G^n(\alpha))\leq G^{n+1}(\alpha)$ and $f(G^n(\alpha)) \in C$, therefore $G^{\omega}(\alpha) \in C$.

Comment: Dude. You **really** need to learn some $\LaTeX$. All that LyX made you write this horrible code stuff...

Comment: No need to, the MSE fairy will edit my text anyway. ;)

Comment: You better show up tomorrow, because I am gonna slap you silly for that remark! :-P

Comment: But Why is D closed?

Comment: @Vinicius: Just take its closure in M (it's still a subset of C).

Comment: Why? Suppose C is the closure of C' in M[G]. Couldn't the closure of C' in M be "bigger"?

Comment: @Vinicius: If $\alpha$ is a limit point of $D$ in $M$, then it's a limit point in $M[G]$.

Comment: Oh! That's great!